# Как проверить существует ли файл?

Tags: delphi

При входе в программу если нету файла `user86x.dll` чтобы не заходил и показал сообщение. `user86x.dll` находиться в  разделе `C:\Windows\System32\` но сейчас в папке `System32` нету файла `user86x.dll` но в программу все равно заходить. Вопрос как мне это реализовать.

```
fileNames :=('C:\Windows\System32\user86x.dll');
    if FileExists(fileNames)=False then
    else
    begin
        ShowMessage('упс!(^_^)');
        Halt;
    end;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if FileExists(fileNames)=False then
else
  halt
```

тоже самое, что и

```
if FileExists(fileNames) then
  halt
```

то есть у Вас сейчас сообщение на наличие файла.

Нужно

```
if not FileExists(fileNames) then 
  halt
```

Просто не то логическое выражение использовано.

Comment: ты имеешь виду таким образом fileNames :=('C:\Windows\System32\user86x.dll');
    if not FileExists(fileNames)then

        halt;
    else

    begin
      ShowMessage('óïñ!(^_^)');
      //Halt;
    end;

Comment: if fileexists  - условие выполняется. if fileexists = false не выполняется.

Comment: сейчас в тексте вопроса showmessage срабатывает при наличии файла user86x.dll, а не наоборот как задумывалось.

Comment: @delphi, у вас перепутаны местами ветки then и else. Или else перенесите в then или инвертируйте условие.